# Ansible trim extension name

Tags: list, ansible

I want to get list of name files without full path and without extension name into 2 differents variable, I succeed for the first one, but not on second one.

I have a variable found_files which contains list files on folder

```
- name: Get only file names
  set_fact:
    file_names: "{{ found_files['files'] | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | list }}"

- name: Get name without extension
  set_fact:
    file_names_without_extension: "{{ item | splitext | first | splitext | first }}"                                                                                          with_list: "{{ file_names }}"
```

the first task, I get the correct name of files without path,
but the second task I get only the first file withtout extension file, and  don't succeed to get all file name without extension name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *map* *splitext* and *first*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        file_names_without_extension: "{{ file_names|
                                          map('splitext')|
                                          map('first')|
                                          list }}"
      vars:
        file_names:
          - test1.txt
          - test2.txt
          - test3.txt
```

gives

```yaml
  file_names_without_extension:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
```

Comment: thanks for your replying, but I get this : ok: [localhost] => (item=<generator object do_map at 0x7faeb18ebd70>) => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7faeb18ebd70>"

I get a message address

Comment: I see. Add the list filter.